# How to determine which condition was true?

Tags: c, performance

Say I have a few conditions inside a `if` statement:

```
if(x < 0 || x > 10 || x == 5)
{

}
```

If either `x` is greater than 10 or less than 0 or equal to 5, I want the program to stop working.

```
if(x < 0 || x > 10 || x == 5)
{
    stop(); // PSEUDO CODE
}
```

**However**, I want the program to say something depending on which condition was true. Something like this:

```
if(x < 0 || x > 10 || x == 5)
{
    if(x < 0)
    {
        printf("your number was less than 0");
    }

    if(x > 10)
    {
        printf("your number was greater than 10");
    }

    if(x == 5)
    {
        printf("wow, your number is equal to 5!");
    }

    stop(); // PSEUDO CODE
}
```

That's a horrible way of doing it because it unnecessarily checks for the conditions twice; how can I do the same in a more efficient way?

Comment: `if(x < 0 || x > 10 || x == 5)` check is redundant and not needed. Also, use `else if` instead of `if`, like this - `if (x<0) {...} else if (x>10) {...} else if (x==5) {...}`

Comment: @H.S. How is this check redundant? Without that check you would need to move `stop();` into each of the 3 inner `if`-blocks causing an even worse (IMHO) redundancy.

Comment: @Gerhardh This check is redundant in a way that the check for `x` - `x < 0`, `x > 10` and `x == 5` are repeated which is not needed. Of course, when I said redundant, I also mean that there are much better ways to ensure `stop()` will only be called when any of these conditions will be `true` and the posted answers already include those ways. Neither I mean nor I said that call `stop()` in every `if` block and a better way would be to have a _flag_ set in the `if` blocks and call `stop()` only if that _flag_ is `true` (somewhat like the dbush answer posted below).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why make things complicated? Just remove the outer check, and put `stop()` inside both of the inner ones:

```
if(x < 0)
{
    printf("your number was less than 0");
    stop();
}

if(x > 10)
{
    printf("your number was greater than 10");
    stop();
}
```

You can even use an `else if` if you want.

Comment: What if instead of`stop()` there's a bunch of lines of code or even more `OR` conditions inside of the `if` statement? Wouldn't copy and pasting be a bad decision? Or the compiler will ignore those lines of code if the condition isn't true?

Comment: If there's a bunch of lines of code, then create a function, put all of the code in there, and just call it in both places.

Comment: Else if would be better. If you have (or chance to have) more than 3 conditions, then using switch is also recommended.

Answer (score 2):

Save the boolean result in a variable and reuse it inside. Redundancy is ok sometimes. Just check/count the number of executions if it's possible to be lessen down.

```
bool isXNegative = x < 0;
bool isXMoreThan = x > 10;
bool isXFive = (x == 5);

//for specific conditions
if(isXNegative)
{
    printf("your number was less than 0");
}

if(isXMoreThan)
{
    printf("your number was greater than 10");
}

if(isXFive)
{
    printf("wow, your number is equal to 5!");
}

//for combination of the conditions.
if(isXNegative || isXMoreThan || isXFive)
{
    //common code here for all the conditions.
    stop(); // PSEUDO CODE
}
//else if(another condition combination here...){...}
//else {...}
```

Comment: [stop with this systems hungarian nonsense](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_notation#Systems_Hungarian_vs._Apps_Hungarian) the compiler can track the types better than you

Comment: @RyanHaining that topic is irrelevant. whatever notation in coding i choose, my goal is to answer OPs problem. it's another story. and i have reasons why i chose to prefix my variables. it's a long explanation. also i don't follow the `best practices` some random people/article posts in the internet. i always evaluate my work/code against the `trends`.

Comment: When you answer questions that seem to come from beginners, you're gonna get more criticism of your styles so OP won't think that prefixing their bools with `b` is commonly accepted as a good idea.

Comment: i expected criticisms before writing any post in any social net. so that does not bother me. whatever style we choose, there will be critics on the other side so it seems an impossible thing not be criticized. like the case of `malloc` and `new`, `goto` and `no-goto`, `politicianA` and `politicianB`, etc. but yeah your right. i think i should follow the naming use by the OP so it will seems more comportable to them. and also, i didn't mention/enforce in the answer to follow my style, it's just that, it's automatic to me. it's still on anyone's choice to acquire an info or not.

Comment: @RyanHaining o gee, hahah i just read your link on the 1st comment. i don't use hungarian. we use different system of naming variables at work. i think im understanding why you discourage people using the hungarian. but it's their choice. let them choose what's easy for them or what their company has chosen.

Answer (score 1):

You can set a flag in the failure cases, then check the flag afterward to do the cleanup.

```
int do_stop = 0;
if(x < 0)
{
    printf("your number was less than 0");
    do_stop = 1;
}

if(x > 10)
{
    printf("your number was greater than 10");
    do_stop = 1;
}

if(x == 5)
{
    printf("wow, your number is equal to 5!");
    do_stop = 1;
}

if (do_stop) {
    stop();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you do want to be complicated, save some keystrokes and take advantage of short-circuiting, you can assign expression results to variables in the `if` condition like so:

```
  int c1, c2, c3;
  if ((c1 = x < 0) || (c2 = x > 10) || (c3 = x == 5)) {
    if (c1) {
      printf("your number was less than 0\n");
    } else if (c2) {
      printf("your number was greater than 10\n");
    } else {
      printf("wow, your number is equal to 5!\n");
    }
  }
```

Just be aware that if the condition short-circuits (say `x < 0`), then the value of `c2` and `c3` is not initialized.

I don't actually advocate writing your code this way, but this language feature can be useful and I didn't see it mentioned.